# Reading from a file, one word at a time by calling a method in Java

Tags: java

The goal is to write at least one other (static) method (function) for my main program to call. Perhaps a
method that processes a single line. Then the main program can call it repeatedly, as long as data is still
in the file. I am not able to create a function for my main program to call it. Maybe my thought process is not working at the moment would someone please help?

I've tried creating a method called readFile() as shown at the bottom, but i am receiving an error with using the scanner

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Scanner for user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //String variables for inputting the filename of the file and sending the text to the output.
    String inputFileName;

    System.out.print("Enter the filename with your student data:\n");

    inputFileName = input.nextLine();
    File fileInput = new File(inputFileName);


    //final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInput));

     if(fileInput.exists()) {
     System.out.print("File has been successfully opened.\n");
     readFile();

         }
      else
       {
        System.out.print("Failed to open " + inputFileName + " file");
        System.out.print("\nExiting Program...");
        System.exit(0);

       }

    System.out.print("No more data.\nGoodbye!");
    input.close();  


    }

public static void readFile() {

     Scanner output;
        try {

//I get an error on this line ----> output = new Scanner ();

            while(output.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print("Line 1 contains these tokens:\n");
            String a = output.next();
            String b = output.next();
            String c = output.next();
            String d = output.next();
            String e = output.next();
            System.out.print(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c +  "\n" + d + "\n" + e + "\n");
            System.out.print("Line 2 contains these tokens:\n");
            String f = output.next();
            String g = output.next();
            String h = output.next();
            String i = output.next();
            String j = output.next();
            String k = output.next();
            System.out.print(f +"\n" + g + "\n" + h +  "\n" + i + "\n" + j + "\n" + k + "\n");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.print("Exception is caught here");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

the error i get with the Scanner:

Multiple markers at this line
    - The constructor Scanner() is 
     undefined
    - Resource leak: 'output' is never

Comment: There is no constructor for `Scanner` without arguments.

Comment: Why are you calling the local variable through which you *read* your **input** data, `output`?

Answer (score 0):

You are validating your `fileInput` in main, and then ignoring that `File` and creating a new `Scanner` (incorrectly) in `readFile`. Instead construct a `Scanner` and pass it to `fileInput`. Like,

```
public static void readFile(Scanner output) {
    // Scanner output
```

And pass a `Scanner` in (and use `try-with-Resources` to close it safely). Like

```
try (Scanner output = new Scanner(fileInput)) {
    readFile(output);
}
```

Also consider reading an entire line and splitting on white-space

```
while (output.hasNextLine()) { // Use if to only read one line.
    System.out.println("Line contains these tokens:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output.nextLine().split("\\s+")));
}
```

(you currently have a lot of hardcoded token variables).

Comment: My goodness, thank you sir. I hard coded the variables due to me just testing out the output, because that goal was to read each word in the file to a new line instead of printing it a whole line at a time.